# How to make nvim highlight SQL code in TypeScript files?

Tags: neovim, treesitter

Example:

```js
const user = await ctx.pool.one(sql.type(userSchema)`
  UPDATE users
  SET avatar = NULL
  WHERE id = ${currentUser.id}
  RETURNING *
`);
```

I'm trying to use [treesitter injection](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#injections) to do it.

So I've written the following query:

```
(call_expression
    function: (call_expression
    function: (member_expression
      object: (identifier) @_obj (#eq? @_obj "sql")))
  (template_string) @injection.content 
  (#set! injection.language "sql"))
```

checked it using [treesitter playground](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/playground) (btw, how to run a query inside nvim? Seems that `:EditQuery` does not exist in an editor, but `:InspectTree` exists), and placed it here `~/.config/nvim/after/queries/typescript/injections.scm`.

But SQL code in typescript files still haven't highlighted. I tried to use `(#set! injection.include-children)`, but it also doesn't work for me.

Treesitter has been installed correctly with the SQL parser. Setup:

```lua
require'nvim-treesitter.configs'.setup {
  -- A list of parser names, or "all" (the five listed parsers should always be installed)
  ensure_installed = { "c", "lua", "vim", "vimdoc", "query", "javascript", "typescript", "sql" },

  -- Install parsers synchronously (only applied to `ensure_installed`)
  sync_install = false,

  -- Automatically install missing parsers when entering buffer
  -- Recommendation: set to false if you don't have `tree-sitter` CLI installed locally
  auto_install = true,

  highlight = {
    enable = true,

    -- Setting this to true will run `:h syntax` and tree-sitter at the same time.
    -- Set this to `true` if you depend on 'syntax' being enabled (like for indentation).
    -- Using this option may slow down your editor, and you may see some duplicate highlights.
    -- Instead of true it can also be a list of languages
    additional_vim_regex_highlighting = false,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it.

First, I had to add `injection.include-children`:

```
(call_expression
    function: (call_expression
    function: (member_expression
      object: (identifier) @_obj (#eq? @_obj "sql")))
  (template_string) @injection.content 
  (#set! injection.language "sql")
  (#set! injection.include-children))
```

Secondly, I placed the file in the wrong place. Seems that the `queries` directory should be placed in one the following paths:

```
:lua print(vim.inspect(vim.api.nvim_list_runtime_paths()))
```

In my case, I just put `queries` directory inside `~/.config/nvim` (before it was in `~/config/nvim/after`).

Comment: You can put queries inside `~/.config/nvim/after/queries` but in the `injections.scm` file, you also need `;; extends` at the top of the file.